# Public dovecot namespace visible only to some users

Tags: dovecot, access-control-list, namespaces

I have a dovecot IMAP server (version 2.1.7) with Maildirs and a virtual user setup (e.g. all accounts are mapped to the same system user). I’d like to create a public namespace shared between users `A` and `B`, but not any other user.

I tried to set up the namespace as follows:

```
namespace {
  type = public
  separator = .
  prefix = INBOX.XFeeds.
  location = maildir:/var/vhosts/feeds:INDEX=~/Maildir/feeds/
  subscriptions = no
}
```

together with a acl-file:

```
/var/vhosts/feeds $ cat dovecot-acl
user=A lrwstipekxa
user=B lrwipk
```

Now user `C` cannot access the contents of the XFeeds mailbox, but it still hows up in its IMAP client. How can I make sure that other users cannot observe that this namespace exists?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to achieve this is to disable the namespace by default:

```
namespace foo {
  type = public
  separator = .
  prefix = INBOX.XFeeds.
  location = maildir:/var/vhosts/feeds:INDEX=~/Maildir/feeds/
  subscriptions = no
  list = no
}
```

and enable it for selected users via userdb. E.g. if you are using a password file, put

```
username:{MD5}password::::::userdb_namespace/foo/list=yes
```

in the file. (Thanks to Steffen Kaiser on the [dovecot mailinglist](http://www.dovecot.org/list/dovecot/2013-October/092993.html) for helping with this.)